# How to select other table details from the selected database result using mssql?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

i have 4 tables Job, team, team_members, staff.I am retreiving the data from Job table.

I need to select the staff name who is the leader.So staff name is in staff table and staff_type column in team members table.In team members table includes team_id.

Comment: `Join team_members tm ON t.team_id = tm.team_id and tm.staff_type = 'leader'`. And also `JOIN staff s on tm.staff_id = s.staff_id`. I'm not sure how you'd do that in php code, but that's how you would in SQL.

Comment: @WEI_DBA i tried but its selecting both staff types(other and leader)

Comment: @WEI_DBA i need to select only the staff type leader..becoz of selecting two staff type..the final results showing twice instead of one result

Comment: Try moving the staff type down to the `Where` clause... `and tm.staff_type = 'leader'`

Comment: @WEI_DBA i have added $this->db->where('tm.Staff_type', "Leader");

Comment: @WEI_DBA  now showing only first result .Please check my expected output result above.From the expected output,second is not showing up

Comment: All  leader names of the team(2,3) i need to show up..Now only 2 is showing in the result..3 is not coming in the finalresult

Answer (score 0):

### The below join query with the where condition can be used to get the desired result for your problem.

```
select * from job j
inner join team t on j.team_id=t.team_id
inner join team_members tm on tm.team_id=t.team_id
inner join staff s on s.staff_type = tm.staff_type
where s.staff_type='leader'
```